# I want to limit this foreach() loop in PHP to 2 outputs

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach, opencart, footer

This is the loop I want to limit this to 2 outputs and create another loop for further outputs please help.. I am a beginner

Enter code here

```
<?php if ($informations) { ?>
<div class="column">
    <h3>
        <?php echo $text_information; ?>
    </h3>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($informations as $information){ ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $information['href']; ?>">
        <?php echo $information['title']; ?>
        </a></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Please be more specific what you want! So you want to "limit" your foreach loop to only run twice? And then you want another loop for the rest of the iterations?

Comment: Don't understand what you need. Can you please show us input data (`$informations`) and expected output?

Comment: Before completely spamming StackOverflow with newbie questions you have so far I suggest to improve your knowledge and experience so that you don't have to start each question with *I am a newbie/beginner*. StackOverflow is supposed to be for experienced programmers and enthusiasts - so show us some enthusiasm to improve your experience. Also use Google for such beginner questions, these have no benefit for SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. .

```
<?php if ($informations) { ?>
      <div class="column">
          <h3><?php echo $text_information; ?></h3>
          <ul>
             <?php
    $i=1;
     foreach ($informations as $information){
        if($i==2)
       {
           break;
       }
     ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $information['href']; ?>"><?php echo                                                      $information['title']; ?></a></li>
        <?php
    $i++;

     } ?>
       </ul>
         </div>
             <?php } ?>
```

For other values . .

```
<?php if ($informations) { ?>
          <div class="column">
              <h3><?php echo $text_information; ?></h3>
              <ul>
                 <?php
        $i=1;
         foreach ($informations as $information){
            if($i<2)
           {
               continue;
           }
         ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $information['href']; ?>"><?php echo                                                      $information['title']; ?></a></li>
            <?php
        $i++;

         } ?>
           </ul>
             </div>
                 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: It will limit your output to 2 phase. .

Answer (score 0):

Bit vague but I guess you are looking for [**array_chunk**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php),

```
$new_array = array_chunk($informations, 2, true);
```